# PHP array for jQuery Remote Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I am trying to get remote autocomplete array

```
$items = array(
    "PR-1001"=>"Product 1",
    "PR-1002"=>"Product 2"
);
```

Input autocomplete suggection will be PR-1001 and PR-1002 and div will be appended with Product 0 or Product 2 depending on selection of autocomplete. I tried using following code but can't Please help me to get array as mentioned above.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($results);
$count = mysql_num_rows($results);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $codes =array("{$row['pr_code']}");
    $names =array("{$row['pr_name']}");
        $i = 0;
        $items[$i] = "\"" . $codes[$i] ."\"=>\"" . $names[$i] ."\", ";
        $items = implode(", ", $items);
        $i++;   
    }
```

I need a php array that show print_r

```
Array ( [DJ-1001] => Product 1 [DJ-1002] => Product 2 )
```

Thank you in advance.

---

Here's answer

```
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
  $items[$row['pr_code']] = $row['pr_name'];
}
```

Thank you friends!

Answer (score 1):

Without having any idea what your schema looks like:

```
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $items[$row['pr_code']] = $row['pr_name'];
}
echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I got this result {"DJ-1001":"Product 1","DJ-1002":"Product 2"} I am trying to get it as $items = array( "PR-1001"=>"Product 1","PR-1002"=>"Product 2");

Comment: @Saleem the result you described is the JavaScript equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

in `PHP` you can have associative array where the key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type. given that you can do straight assignement of `key=>value` from your query and then return the array in [json](http://www.json.org/) (jquery-ui autocomplete it's modeled around it so just take a snippet from the official documentation to see how it works):

```
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $items[$row['pr_code']] = $row['pr_name'];

echo json_encode($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:

• An Array of Strings:
[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]

• An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

```
$arr   = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
    array_push($arr,'{ label: "' . $row['pr_code'] . '", value: "' . $row['pr_name'] . '" }'); 
}

echo "[" . implode(',',$arr) . "]";
```